# Can one display an entire unmodified website on top of another one in a lightbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, lightbox

Is it possible to do this with just javascript/jquery/ajax?
The idea is to make another website display unmodified i.e. display the pure html of the site in a view that hovers over the current view like a lightbox as opposed to in a new window or tab as one usually has in a browser.

Any descriptions, examples, or basic to advanced tutorials and books would be helpful here.

Thanks!

Comment: the question is whether a lightbox can do that. I am used to seeing it used for pictures and simple XML but i don't know if it can display a full html page directly without scraping?

Comment: yup, most lightboxes can show iframe content. have a look at this list : http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/

Answer (score 2):

IF you want the completely usmodified version, the easiest way is to go with is `<iframe>`

Example:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

If you are looking for a lightbox capable of showing iframe or html, here is a list (Thanks to JohnP) http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/

Comment: Thanks...is there a way to make an iframe behave like a lightbox though? If i want to maximize the iframe for example but dont want it to maximize on the "same page" but instead maximize on top of the page like the lightbox for pictures?

Comment: Yes, it is possible but Why dont you use lightbox instead and save the trouble?

Comment: But does lightbox work for displaying web pages? I thought it worked only for images....please show me some example code or links to useful resources for using lightbox to display web pages? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, ShadowBox of Michael J.I Jackson does that, http://www.shadowbox-js.com/index.html

Comment: Thanks! so just to confirm...even though that I don't have access to the html of a page...if i just have the http://webAddress.com/page type of link ShadowBox will display the unmodified page in a lightbox?

Comment: Yes, it does. But Shadow Box is not available for commercial use, you can learn from it, but not use it commercially. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the plugin from here - > http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Then if you set it up to with an iframe in the same way as you would for an image, it should work.